# WiX - Verifying Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.2 Developer Pack in WiX installer package

Tags: wix

How to verify  Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.2 Developer Pack is installed or not as part of WiX installer package during installation.
Thanks in advance,
Ravi

Comment: The developer pack installs several components as indicated at : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2901951.  Do you want to verify if the developer pack is installed or do you just want to check if  .Net framework 4.5.2 is installed?

Comment: I just need to verify if the developer pack is installed or not.

Comment: Have you checked the following: http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/redistributables_and_install_checks/check_for_dotnet.html    http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/customactions/wixnetfxextension.html   to see if a combination of the various properties would help? I am saying this since the developer pack seems to install several packages at once. You might just be able to combine the different properties to achieve what you want, unless there is a better approach available.